# Unable to install RStudio on Mac OSX 10.10

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, osx-mavericks

I run R 3.2.0 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build (6931) and the latest version of RStudio (0.99.xx). On startup, I get an error message:

> ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in
>   .Internal(getOption(x)) :  there is no .Internal function 'getOption'
>   ]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error
>   rstudio::r::exec::evaluateString(const std::string &, SEXP *,
>   sexp::Protect *) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:272

The only option is to click OK then exit, no menu, just a blank page. I've tried deleting older versions of R but that doesn't work.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R and RStudio, clearing older versions of R, resetting RStudio's state, basically everything short of creating a partition to run just R and RStudio. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Does R start normally outside RStudio. And have your trashed the invisible `.RData` and `.Rhistory` files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by deleting all R/RStudio resources which remained from installing them manually from .dmg:

1. Uninstall CRAN R GUI app (drag it into the trash)
2. Uninstall RStudio app (drag it into the trash)
3. From Terminal:

   $ rm -rf ~/.rstudio-desktop/

   $ rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/R.framework /Applications/R.app /usr/bin/R /usr/bin/Rscript

You may still have some other files left.  See:

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-OS-X

I ignored these files.

Finally, reinstall r/rstdio via brew:

```
$ brew install r
$ brew cask install rstudio
```

Then you should be able to launch RStudio from ~/Applications.  If it still doesn't work, check that what you have installed from brew is up to date.